# Dynamically change the delay time of an observable in rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a service that requests some data and returns an `Observable`, I use `repeatWhen` to replay this request continuously after a delay time:

```
this.delay = 2000;
var observ = this.myService.getData()
            .repeatWhen(completed => completed.delay(this.delay));
this.mySubscription = observ.subscribe(val => this.handleResponse(val));
```

I wish to be able to modify the value of the `delay` dynamically, let's say inside the `handleResponse` method. How can I achieve that?

For example (pseudo code):

```
private handleResponse(val: boolean) {
    if(val)
        this.delay += 2000;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the

```
.repeatWhen(completed => completed.delay(this.delay));
```

your observable is already changed and got it's value from the `this.delay`. After it, if you will change `this.delay`, it will never affect the above `repeatWhen`. The observable is already created with the initial value of `delay`, it ***does not go every time*** and get the value from `this.delay`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a clean way to achieve this behavior, or should I somehow rebuild the entire observable each time?

Comment: You need to every time complete the current observable to not let memory leaks and create a new one with changed delay.

Comment: When you say Complete the observable, how can i ensure it's completion when using a repeatWhen ?

Comment: If anyone is looking at this and wants to keep the repeatwhen. Use a timer and switchMap for the request. Then use a filter with it. This can block it going into the subscribe block.